# Proportion questioning

Tags: algebra-precalculus

2 firms make the following charges for renting a car over the weekend .

Firm A - Has a fixed charge of $320, and Charged 50 cents per km for every km over 300

Firm B - has a fixed charge of $60 and charge 70 cents per km traveled .

Find the number of kilometres traveled for which the cost of hiring a car from either firm A or firm B will be the same .

In this case I assumed that the distance traveled will be more than 300 km . And I let it be $x.$

$$320 + (0.5)(x - 300) ) = 60 + (0.7)(x)$$ 
$$0.5x - 0.7 x = 60 - 170$$

$x = 550$ km

how do I approach this question without having to assume?

Comment: You should not assume that the distance traveled will be more than 300 km IMO. Split it into two cases and solve two different equations: For $x<300$, solve $320=60+0.7x$. For $x\geq300$, solve $320+0.5(300-x)=60+0.7x$. And of course, rule out any solution that doesn't 
"make sense".

Comment: BTW, your mistake is that "$320$" at the end. It should be "$170$", can you see why?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption turns out to be correct, but it is better to *prove* it. You already know that the price for firm A will be $\$320$ if $x\le300$ km; can you prove that the price for firm B must be less than $\$320$ in such a case?

To see how you erred in finding your answer, expand the expression $$0.5(x-300).$$